# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' when I save in amage

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, attributes

I want to save the picture from site, but when i`m trying to print

```
pict_link
```

the following error has occured. Because of this, the whole loop stops and the program stops working. I tried to work through `[.attrs]`, but this also did not help. I need your help.

```py
import sys, os, requests, datetime, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

def get_html(url):
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return r.content

def pictures(pict_link, file):
      img = requests.get(pict_link) 
      out = open(file, "wb") 
      out.write(img.content) 
      out.close()


link = 'https://www.clubx.com.au/products/womanizer-pro?variant=37834367948'
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_html(link), 'html.parser')
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('./phantomjs/bin/phantomjs')
browser.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
box = soup.find('div',{'class':'swatch clearfix'})
rows = box.find_all('div')[1:]
nn = 1
for row in rows:
    pict_link = row.find('img').get('src')
    print(pict_link)
    codice = link.split('/products/')[1].split('?variant')[0] + '_' + str(nn)
    foto = './Pictures/' + codice + '.jpg'
    name_foto = codice + '.jpg'
    pictures(pict_link, foto)
    label = 'pict_' + str(nn)
    nn += 1
browser.quit()
```

Comment: Can you add the stack trace? It's not very clear from the question where exactly the error is thrown. Stack trace would help us in debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) is clear  about this:

> If `find()` can’t find anything, it returns None

Change

```
pict_link = row.find('img').get('src')
```

to something like

```
pict = row.find('img')
if pict is None:
    continue
pict_link = pict.get('src')
```